# Tfs connect project and map it

Tags: azure-devops

I'am having problem with team foundation server.(http://tfs.visualstudio.com/). I created project from there(http://tfs.visualstudio.com/). And I click Open New Instance of Visual Studio.

[image]

And Team Explorer is look like:

[image]

Then i click File>New Project and clicked Add to Source Control and selected My project name in TFS. So i uploaded my project and it added to my tfs project. But i dont know how can i share my project in tfs. I tried this:

[image]

Entered my friend live id(hotmail). Then he signed up and he did same steps like me. But how can he download project that already exist? I did not see specific setting for that.

[image]

What i must supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He must use the menu File > Open > Team Project. Visual Studio will probably ask for a TFS server, when you set the server URL, he will be able to see the collections and projects, then, he can open the project.

Or, on the window you showed (Team Explorer), he can click on Source Control Explorer and open the solution from there.

Visual Studio will ask for a mapping directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect to Team Foundation Service via VS 2008 following steps have to be done,

1. Install VS 2008 SP1, Team Explorer 2008 and GDR update (VS90SP1-KB2673642-x86)
2. Connect manually to Team Foundation Service
    Team Explorer -> Servers -> Add -> type 
   `https://[YourAccount].visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection`

Make sure to add `/DefaultCollection`.